# SYN Flooding Attack

Tags: apache, sysctl, flooding, syn

I am trying to stop SYN Flooding Attack

but when I set
net.ipv4.tcp_syncookies = 1

in sysctl.conf

I get this error

/proc/sys/net/ipv4/tcp_syncookies: No such file or directory

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, there's no good news.

Your kernel was not compiled with the option `CONFIG_SYN_COOKIES`, because the default value of `tcp_syncookies` is `1`.

You can TRY to use `sysctl` directly.

```
sysctl -w net.ipv4.tcp_syncookies=1
```

If that fails, there is a larger issue. Your kernel needs to be recompiled (good luck) or your operating system choice needs to be adjusted, whichever you are more comfortable with.

Comment: thank you for your answer but is there any alternative way other than recompile kernel.

Comment: I used mod security but I faced another issue with image upload using base64coding.